# CSS horizontal submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I'm working on the navigation bar for a website and currently the main menu is complete. However, the "Services" and "Products" buttons need to each have their own sub-menu. The sub-menu should normally be hidden from view and appears when the user mouse-overs on the respective button.

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jnLpmxam/) with the desired result. Obviously, I'd rather not use any javascript if possible.

The idea I had initially was to have sub-menu have `position: absolute` with a `z-index` value lower than that of the main-menu, so that it can slide underneath the main-menu. However, doing so messes up with the width if I give it `width: 100%` and since my site is responsive, I avoid static widths.

I also tried doing with relative positioning, but that doesn't work either.

Another thing I don't like with that approach is that the markup for the main menu and sub-menu get split. Is it possible to get the above result, but with this markup?

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Link 4</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-size: 0;
}

.bodyframe {
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.div_container {
    max-width: 1460px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 49px;
}
.nav {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    background: #304770;
    z-index: 10;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #304770;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.nav li a {
    padding: 12px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    display: block;
}

.nav li.active a {
    color: orange;
}

.nav li.active a:before {
    width: 100%;
}

.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #304770;
    color: orange;
    transition: color 0.25s;
}

.nav li a:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    background-color: orange;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s;
    transition: width 0.2s;
}

.nav li:nth-last-of-type(1) a:after {
    display: none;
}

.nav li a:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
}

.nav li a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -8px;
    top: 21px;
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    background: #ffffff;
    opacity: .5;
}

.subnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -49px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.2s;
}

.subnav li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.subnav li a {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bodyframe div_container">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1243</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Why _"Obviously, I'd rather not use any javascript if possible."_? Perhaps this can be done using css transformations or something but I'm not aware of it. But jQuery makes this sort of thing pretty much trivial. Why not use javascript.

Comment: Do you want to have 100% of menu width in subnav?

Comment: I just prefer to keep js to a minimum, unless it doesn't make sense not to use js. If I have no other option, then I don't mind js/jQ.

Comment: @nevermind, I want it as in the fiddle. Both menus have same width.

Comment: Added more CSS and HTML to show how the menus are wrapped inside another container.

Comment: There is one problem with your 'desired' result: submenu is not clickable at all, can't be reached... So, i would use position:absolute, and media queries for smaller screens... E.g. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jnLpmxam/1/ And yes, your suggested html (without separation) is better..

Comment: @nevermind, indeed. I just made that quickly to show how I want the submenu to show/hide. But yeah, buttons need to be clickable.

Comment: @Chris, linked old fiddle, this is right one: http://jsfiddle.net/jnLpmxam/2/

Comment: @nevermind, looks promising! I'll try on the site.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned - for smaller screens - use media queries, doesn't work so great on small screens...

Comment: Hm... some CSS clashes, obviously... Try to check all... nav container (.nav) should be set to position:relative... not li element, it self...

Comment: You can add your answer as solution. I almost got it to work.

Comment: @nevermind, I just realized that your answer doesn't have the submenu slide underneath main menu (see my fiddle). I want the animation.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the submenu to mimic the one in the example, without using jQuery, using the second chunk of HTML with the CSS you supplied you could do:

```
nav:hover~ul {
   top: 0px;
}
```

This shows the next ul element, in this case the subnav, whenever the nav is hovered over ("~" selector means select the ul element preceded by nav:hover).

However, if you want to do something more dynamic... id suggest just using JS/jQuery as well